# How to set the psycopg2 parameters given the URI in SQL workbench?

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

From the this [SQL workbench tutorial](https://blog.openbridge.com/definitive-guide-for-connecting-sql-workbench-j-to-amazon-redshift-57d06aa32805)

Given the URI:

> jdbc:redshift://sample.redshift.openbridge.io:5439/sample_database?ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

Additionally, I just need the `Username` and `Password` to connect to the redshift server on AWS.

If I'm using `psycopg2` in Python, I would require the following fields to establish a connection to the database:

- `dbname`
- `host`
- `port`
- `user`
- `password`

E.g.

```
import psycopg2
con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'dbname', host='host', 
                     port= 'port', user= 'user', password= 'pwd')
con.connect()
```

Given the URI as shown above, I figured these values:

- `dbname` = `sample.redshift.openbridge.io`
- `host` = `jdbc:redshift://`
- `port` = `5439`
- `user` = The Username to connect as like the SQL workbench
- `password` = My Password for the user

But I think the values I've tried to split up from the URI is wrong:

```
import psycopg2
dbname='sample.redshift.openbridge.io'
host='jdbc:redshift'
port=5439
user='Username'
password='Password'
con=psycopg2.connect(dbname, host, port, user, password)

OperationalError: could not translate host name "jdbc:redshift:" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

**What would be the appropriate values for the `psycopg2` parameters given the URI above?**

How about the `ssl=true` and `sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` settings and 
`sample_database` database? **How do I set these as the `con` parameters in psycopg2?**

My environment settings:

- Mac OS X
- Python 3
- `psycopg2.__version__` = 2.7.3.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)

---

I've got it to work with:

```
import psycopg2
dbname='sample_database'
host='sample.redshift.openbridge.io'
port=5439
user='Username'
password='Password'
con=psycopg2.connect(dbname, host, port, user, password)
```

But I'm not sure about the ssl properties that was set for the connection.

**Is `ssl=true` and `sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` when I connect to through `psycopg2` in the above manner?**

**Does the `psycopg2` automatically set `jdbc:redshift` as the protocol?**

Comment: I think you mixed up the values for `dbname` and `host`.

Comment: When I swap the values for `dbname` and `host`, I get `OperationalError: FATAL:  database "jdbc:redshift" does not exist` =(

Comment: Do not know much about Redshift. But from the URL, the database is `sample_database`.

Comment: I've got it to work with the updates on the question but I'm still unclear what's happening. =(

Comment: What is not clear? `jdbc:redshift` is not a host, just a driver to connect to the DB.

Comment: It's unclear what are the flags set by `psycopg2`? e.g. I supposed `ssl=true` but for `sslfactory` how did psycopg2 know it's `com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`? Pretty magical to me =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the URL:

> jdbc:redshift://sample.redshift.openbridge.io:5439/sample_database?ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

```
host: sample.redshift.openbridge.io
port: 5439
database: sample_database
```

Comment: do you know the replacement for sslfactory parameter? for ssl=true: "instances of ssl=true are translated into sslmode=require" (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING)